# How do you declare a circular buffer?

Tags: c

```
/**
 * ring_buffer_set - update the ring buffer with the given value
 * @lq_recv: pointer to the ring buffer
 * @lq_index: index to store the value at
 * @value: value to store in the ring buffer
 */
static void ring_buffer_set(uint8_t lq_recv[], uint8_t *lq_index,
                   uint8_t value)
{
    lq_recv[*lq_index] = value;
    *lq_index = (*lq_index + 1) % 64;
}

/**
 * ring_buffer_set - compute the average of all non-zero values stored
 * in the given ring buffer
 * @lq_recv: pointer to the ring buffer
 *
 * Returns computed average value.
 */
static uint8_t ring_buffer_avg(const uint8_t lq_recv[])
{
    const uint8_t *ptr;
    uint16_t count = 0, i = 0, sum = 0;

    ptr = lq_recv;

    while (i < 64) {
        if (*ptr != 0) {
            count++;
            sum += *ptr;
        }

        i++;
        ptr++;
    }

    if (count == 0)
        return 0;

    return (uint8_t)(sum / count);
}
```

1) `lq_recv[]` is circular buffer but it looks like a plain array?

2) What's the purpose of `*lq_index = (*lq_index + 1) % 64`?

Comment: You can only define bog-standard arrays/buffers. How you use them is your decision, even if you decide to use them as circular buffers.

Comment: "Circular buffer" is a concept, and to my knowledge no language implements it as a primitive.  How it's implemented as an API can vary considerably.  As the answers state, the common way is to use an array and have special logic that deals with how you increment the array index.

Answer (score 5):

1. A "circular buffer" is an array that's used in a particular way. It's not declared any differently from any other array.
2. It's updating the index of the array that's read from and keeping it within the bounds of the array.

Answer (score 4):

1. Circular buffer is of course a plain array, but you reset the array indexers once it comes to the last element.
2. Use of modulus operator (%) ensures that array index is reset to 0 once it comes to the last element.

Comment: @lilzz Because otherwise the index wouldn't be updated in the main program when incremented. The only other way to do it would be to return the new index. Since the index is updated automatically by the function anyway, why not go one step further and make the function update the relevant index itself? It also makes for cleaner code to do `func(buffer, &i);` instead of `i = func(buffer, i);`